# Crash on std::thread destructor with VS CTP 14

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio, c++14

I'm implementing a concurrency library with interruptible threads like those in boost and Java based on the standard library in C++11 using Visual Studio CTP 14.

After some refactoring I encountered a crash (sometimes trying to dereference a null pointer, sometimes "Debug Error! R6010" and sometimes no crash at all) inside std::thread's destructor. After a lot of code stripping to find the issue I am no closer to understanding if the issue is with my code or if it could be a compiler bug.

Even after stripping out code there's still a lot left required to reproduce the issue, so bear with me please :)

Parts of the thread wrapper implementation:

```
class InterruptException : public std::exception
{
public:
    const char* what() const override {return "InterruptException";}
};

class Thread
{
public:
    Thread(const Thread&) = delete;
    Thread& operator=(const Thread&) = delete;

    Thread();

    template <typename Callable>
    Thread(Callable&& action);

    Thread(Thread&& other);

    ~Thread();

    Thread& operator=(Thread&& other);

    // Sets interruption flag and call notifyAll for current condition if any.
    void interrupt();

    // Throws interrupted exception if current thread interruption flag is set.
    // This also resets the interruption flag.
    static void interruptionPoint();

    static void interruptCurrent();


    static void setCondition(std::condition_variable* cond);
    static Thread* currentThread(Thread* setter = nullptr);

private:
    std::atomic<bool>                       _interruptionFlag;
    std::atomic<std::condition_variable*>   _currentCondition;
    std::thread _stdThread;
};

template <typename Callable>
Thread::Thread(Callable&& action)
: _stdThread(),
  _interruptionFlag(false),
  _currentCondition(nullptr)
{
    _stdThread = std::thread(
        [this, runner = std::move(action)]
        {
            currentThread(this);

            try
            {
                runner();
            }
            catch (InterruptException&)
            {
                // Normal exit.
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                // Removed logging calls.
            }
        }
    );
}

Thread::~Thread()
{
    // Block at thread destruction, no detached thread support.
    if (_stdThread.joinable())
    {
        interrupt();
        _stdThread.join();
    }
}

// (More code if requested.)
```

(Do note that above code is missing parts for clarity)

I've written several tests for the Thread class and it seems to work as one would expect. The next part is a stripped down version of a task runner.

```
template <typename Runner>
class StrippedSystem
{
public:
    template <typename... CtorArgs>
    StrippedSystem(CtorArgs&&... args);

    StrippedSystem(const StrippedSystem&) = delete;
    StrippedSystem(StrippedSystem&&) = delete;

    // ...

private:
    template <typename... CtorArgs>
    Thread createRunnerThread(CtorArgs&&... args);

    std::mutex _mutex;
    std::condition_variable _cond;

    Thread _runner;
};

template <typename Runner>
template <typename... CtorArgs>
StrippedSystem<Runner>::StrippedSystem(CtorArgs&&... args)
{
    _runner = createRunnerThread(std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...);
}

template <typename Runner>
template <typename... CtorArgs>
Thread StrippedSystem<Runner>::createRunnerThread(CtorArgs&&... args)
{
    auto runnerProc =
    [&]
    {
        Thread::setCondition(&_cond);

        try
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _cond.wait(
                lock,
                [&]
                {
                    Thread::interruptionPoint();
                    return false;
                }
            );
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            Thread::setCondition(nullptr);
            std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception());
        }
    };

    return Thread(runnerProc);
}
```

The code for the stripped down StrippedSystem is quite simple. It creates a thread that waits until interrupted. When the destructor of Thread is called the interruption flag is set and the condition gets notified. Then the thread runs to an interruption point (inside the _cond.wait lambda) that throws an InterruptionException that is caught in the thread wrapper and the thread exits normally.

Now for the code that crashes everything:

```
struct ConstructedRunner
{
    ConstructedRunner(int a, std::string b)
    : i(a), j(b)
    {
    }

    int i;
    std::string j;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {
        StrippedSystem<ConstructedRunner> testSys2(1, "foobar");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As written above, the crash can be either "Debug Error! abort has been called", Access Violation (trying to dereference a null pointer) or in some cases no crash at all.

After some troubleshooting I have found that the following *does not crash*:

```
struct DummyRunner
{
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {
        StrippedSystem<DummyRunner> testSys1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

After even more troubleshooting I found that in the system constructor replacing

```
_runner = createRunnerThread(std::forward<CtorArgs>(args)...);
```

with

```
_runner = Thread(
        [&]
        {
            Thread::setCondition(&_cond);

            try
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
                _cond.wait(
                    lock,
                    [&]
                    {
                        Thread::interruptionPoint();
                        return false;
                    }
                );
            }
            catch (...)
            {
                Thread::setCondition(nullptr);
                std::rethrow_exception(std::current_exception());
            }
        }
    );
```

Also fixes the crash. *Even though the forwarded arguments are not used.*

This makes no sense to me since the code that's run should be the same. Is this a compiler issue or am I doing something really wrong that's causing some strange concurrency issues?

Building in debug mode with Visual Studio CTP 14 for Windows 7.

Comment: Capturing `std::move(action)` instead of `std::forward<Callable>(action)` in the `Thread` template constructor is suspicious.

Comment: @Casey Tried it now with `std::forward<Callable>` instead, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some help I got the error sorted out.

The issue was with `currentThread(this)` that's in the `Thread` template constructor. That function sets the thread pointer as a thread local static variable that is later read to get the interruption flag and the current condition if any. The problem was that the `this` pointer was referring to a temporary object. This can be seen in the `_runner = Thread(...)` where the temporary `Thread` object is on the right side and is being set as the thread local data. The data was not updated after the thread move.

In the `Thread`'s destructor the `interrupt` checked the thread local flag and that's the reason for the crash in the destructor.